# Checking website TLS protocol version different from Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ssl

I write a program in C#

```
public static void RunClient(string machineName, string serverName)
{
    using (var client = new TcpClient(machineName, 443))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

        using (var sslStream = new SslStream(
            client.GetStream(),
            false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
            null
            ))
        {
            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                client.Close();
                return;
            }

            var request = String.Format("GET https://{0}/  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n", serverName);
            byte[] messsage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);

            sslStream.Write(messsage, 0, messsage.Length);
            sslStream.Flush();

            Console.WriteLine($"Protocol: { sslStream.SslProtocol }");

            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Client closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

The program result is

> Client connected.
>
> Protocol: **Tls12**
>
> Client closed.

But when I check the same web site in Google Chrome, it show that the Protocol is **TLS 1.3**

**Note 2021-07-27**: Just found that .net Framework 4.6 that I use did not support TLS 1.3, thus I've update it to .net framework 4.8 but the result still same.

My question is why the result different? and which result is correct?

Comment: Likely the TLS stack  you use does not support TLS 1.3 or it is not enabled in your program. Note that C# does not use the same TLS stack as Chrome.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so it mean Google Chrome is correct?

Comment: Both are correct. Obviously the site supports at least TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3. It might even support more, check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).